# How to define -1 as a uint64 in a match clause?

Tags: f#

```
let myuint64 = 10uL
match myuint64 with
| -1   -> ()
| _    -> ()
```

How do I define the given -1 as a uint64 value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if F# will convert it for you then -1UL would work. If not then you can specify it as 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFUL and add a comment to remember that it's -1.

Don't have the F# tools installed at the moment so I cannot verify this.

Comment: -1UL does not work in F#.  However 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFUL does work.  Just need confirmation if this is supported.

Comment: You can also use System.UInt64.MaxValue instead of the long constant, as 'ssp' pointed out in their answer.

Comment: This has become the accepted answer, but I think for completeness readers should reference answers below which point out that the u in uint64 means unsigned, so it can't/shouldn't represent a negative number anyway.

Answer (score 6):

```
> match 0UL-1UL with
-   |System.UInt64.MaxValue -> "-1"
-   |_ -> "???"
- ;;
val it : string = "-1"
```

Answer (score 5):

Let me leave alone the fact that you can't really represent a negative value with a data type that can only store positive values (and zero of course).

If, on the other hand, you were storing it in a signed value, -1 would be stored as all bits set.

So basically, I will assume you want to find a way to represent -1 as a bit-wise value that will be compatible with -1 as a signed value.

The value would then be, in C# and C/C++ syntax, 0xffffffffffffffff. Exactly how to specify that in F# I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know F# at all, but if it's anything like any other languages, a UInt64 *can't* be -1.  Ever.  UInt means unsigned integer, which means it can only represent positive values.

Comment: Some languages like C would allow a -1 to be placed in a uint64_t. Since the 2's complement could be thought of as a positive number.

Comment: Well, you can store a bit pattern that represents -1 as a signed integer into an unsigned integer variable. However, using that value will interpret it as a positive value, beyond the upper limit of a signed int.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on other answers:
When a type starts with a **u** it means unsigned. What signed/unsigned means is this:

Numbers are stored using a certain number of bits. In the case of int64 and uint64, 64 bits are used. If the number is signed, the 1st bit is not used as part of the number itself, only the other 63 are. That bit is used to say whether the number is negative. If the number is unsigned, then all bits including the 1st bit are used as part of the number and the number is always non-negative (ie: is positive or 0).

Answer (score 1):

Well you could assign it -1 and on most architectures store the 2's complement in there. The signed and unsigned stuff are really only for the type checking. There is no negative sign in hardware.

I have no idea if f# type checker is smart enough to know that a lexical constant -1 is a negative number and should not be put in a uint64.

C definitely does not care.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <inttypes.h>
 main()
 {
 uint64_t x = -1;
 printf("0x%x\n", x); // 0xffffffff
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with a signed int:

```
-1: int64
```

but you can't match a negative number to a uint, as others have stated.